# Why is Dojo build generating all it's dependencies next to the released dojo.js file?

Tags: javascript, dojo, requirejs

All I want is a bundled version of dojo with is the require loader, domReady, and query and nothing else. I have tried many release.profiles and experimented changing the config.

I tried these too:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/build/customBase.html
http://jamesthom.as/blog/2012/08/03/finding-nano/

This and many other examples generate the whole folder of dojo and all its files next to the dojo.js file. For the past few weeks of experimentation I didn't even realise the dojo.js file was the built version. It's a bit difficult to know that since it's sitting next to all the other dojo files.
Could it be my version of dojo? I'm using 1.8, with latest java 32 bit installed on my version of windows 7.

Any help appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dojo will generate your output layer file in your output directory - as you've discovered - but because the need for some modules that aren't mentioned in your layer file *can* still occur at runtime, Dojo also packages up all the other input files into the output directory too so that they're available on demand.

(It can optionally minify the layer files and those standalone files, separately.)

Having said that, you don't have to *use* those on-demand files:

I've never managed to find a way to stop it doing that copy/transform, so I

1. generate my layer files (being very careful to ensure that I can't possibly need any other modules at runtime)
2. throw away all the other files

It can occasionally be a bit fiddly to ensure that the layer files are complete, but you're talking about a very small set, so it should be okay for your case.

I don't believe there's any sort of straightforward way to stop Dojo generating them in the first place, unfortunately.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

ok thanks very much. I think I found another post which confirms the same. Dojo custom build getting browser errors due to missing resources